# Container Job Azure DevOps on-premises

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an on-premises installation of Azure DevOps 2022, I would like to use Container Jobs for some of the builds. My plan is to run them on a specific Linux agent (RHEL 8) that has already docker installed.

I have read this page: [Define container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops-2022), where there are examples like:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

container: ubuntu:18.04

steps:
- script: printenv
```

Since we are on-premises, I think I cannot use `vmImage`, so I found this other page [about self hosted agents](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/running-container-jobs-on-self-hosted-agents/1108171), where they suggest something like:

```yaml
pool: my_self_hosted_pool_name

container: my_private_docker_registry
```

I tried this:

```yaml
pool:
  name: MyPool

containers: ubuntu:latest
```

But I get a warning that `containers` is not a valid keyword at that level, and the documentation seems to agree with that. I also tried:

```yaml
pool:
  name: MyPool

resources:
  containers:
  - container: linux
    image: ubuntu:22.04
```

But I think this is just the wrong approach.

My question is: is it possible to run container jobs on-premises? if yes, how? Keep in mind that for this particular case, I would like to run the whole build on the container itself, so not only a particular job, but all of them on the same one.

Comment: You are giving containers instead container. The actual code is below. `pool:  name: Defaultcontainer: ubuntu:latest`. The code part is 3 line. Check and let me know if it is working then I will post as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

No you **can't**.

Those vmImages are only for Microsoft-hosted agents and Microsoft-hosted agents are only for Azure Devops Service.

You can try create **dockerfile** and [Run a self-hosted agent in Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops)